# How to style dropdown menu using CSS in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown Menu using HTML and CSS. At present it is simple and working but as per my requirement i want my dropdown to be similar to this image ...
Please refer sample image at..[Sample DropdownImage Image](http://s17.postimg.org/8wdgjey8v/pic.png)

I want my dropdown to change like this as soon as Mouse hover reaches just like this angular design with line in between two links.

Here i have tried to create a fiddle but my jquery is not working fine so my mouse hover event is not working..

Here is my HTML..

```
  <div class='menu'>
                <a class='hover-link'>ABOUT US</a>

                <div class='sub'>
                    <ul class='sub-options'>
                        <li><a href='#'>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please see my fiddle..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WRFf/2/)

Please help my fiddle dropdown On Mouse hover to change just like in image

Comment: Why do you want to use jquery, if its possible with css. Use `:hover`

Comment: @CTravel Its like that i am using no special reasons..

Comment: I suggest you use list items with nested items.. and use css when you can.

Comment: Correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5WRFf/2/

Comment: @CTravel I will thankfull to you if You suggest me in my codes..Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really good step by step guide on how to create a pure CSS dropdown menu.

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

I'd advise doing this to minimize website load, reducing javascript use is usually a good idea, especially since you can use a bunch of animation types in [CSS3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) now!

Comment: The example on that site is simple and straight to the point.